# Using extern "C" __attribute__((visibility("default"))) , then my parameter's name can be different or not?

Tags: c++, c, declaration

Suppose I want to design a API, I declare this function in this way:

```
#define XXAPI extern "C" __attribute__((visibility("default")))
XXAPI my_function(int a, int b, ...);
```

then I define its parameter in different names:

```
XXAPI my_function(int x, int y, ...)
{
   // function body, use C++
}
```

is it legitimate? And why?

Comment: Yes, your function arguments NAMES can be different. The types must be the same.

Comment: Thanks! But I  wonder why? Declaration and Definition don't need the same name in C, but what if in C++ ? Does this relate to "Function Overloading" ?

Comment: @TUMB1EWEED parameter names are not part of a function's signature. So they can be whatever you want, and they can differ between declaration and definition (and even be omitted completely). Function Overloading works by function names and parameter types, not by parameter names.

Comment: You can actually omit the parameter names completely e.g. `XXAPI my_function(int, int, ...);` but I wouldn't recommend that for semantic reasons.